# How to read an ASP.NET internal server error description with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, webclient

Behold the code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        var bytesReceived = client.UploadData("http://localhost", bytesToPost);
        var response = client.Encoding.GetString(bytesReceived);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I am getting this HTTP 500 internal server error when the UploadData method is called. But I can't see the error description anywhere in the "ex" object while debugging. How do I rewrite this code so I can read the error description?

Comment: Does it show anything when you are using FireBug?

Comment: @azamsharp I'm not able to reproduce the error in my browser since it would require me to post some data

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Web servers often return an error page with more details (either HTML or plain text depending on the server). You can grab this by catching `WebException` and reading the response stream from its `Response` property.

Answer (score 1):

I found useful information for debugging this way:

```
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
            String details = "NONE";
            String statusCode = "NONE";
            if (httpWebResponse != null)
            {
                details = httpWebResponse.StatusDescription;
                statusCode = httpWebResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
            }

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            Response.Write("<BR />");
            Response.Write(ex.Status);
            Response.Write("<BR />");
            Response.Write(statusCode);
            Response.Write("<BR />");
            Response.Write(details);
            Response.Write("<BR />");
            Response.Write(ex);
            Response.Write("<BR />");
        }
```

Comment: HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response; // Boom! That's the shizzle that will get your status code dizzle.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching a HttpException and call GetHtmlErrorMessage() on it

Comment: It's a WebException, it won't cast to HttpException. Believe me, I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked

```
Debug.WriteLine( ex.ToString() );
```

Comment: It's not that simple. I want to read the remote server error. Which in this case is "localhost" coincidentally.

Comment: Ahh..missed the concept there. Still calling ToString will usually dump any diagnostic info for most exceptions. Even Web/Http exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.  WebClient is the simplest thing to use to do basic web communication, but it does not provide the functionality you need.  I think it's better to do this because it will not throw an exception.