# WebClient vs. HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, webclient, httpwebresponse

It seems to me that most of what can be accomplished with **`HttpWebRequest/Response`** can also be accomplished with the **`WebClient`** class. I read somewhere that `WebClient` is a high-level wrapper for `WebRequest/Response`.
 So far, I can't see anything that can be accomplished with `HttpWebRequest/Response` that can not be accomplished with `WebClient`, nor where HttpWebRequest/Response will give you more "fine-grained" control.

When should I use WebClient and when `HttpWebRequest/Response`? (Obviously, `HttpWebRequest/Response` are HTTP specific.)

If `HttpWebRequest/Response` are lower level then `WebClient`, what can I accomplish with `HttpWebRequest/Response` that I cannot accomplish with `WebClient`?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Using `HttpWebRequest` gives you more control on the request. You can set cookies, headers, protocol, etc... In the response, you can also retrieve the cookies and headers

Comment: Thomas, still not convinced... WebClient has a Headers property, you can retrieve the cookie like this: String  cookie =  webClient.ResponseHeaders(“Set-Cookie”) and set it: webClient.Headers.Add("Cookie", "CommunityServer-UserCookie…");

Comment: So you have to handle the cookies manually... not very convenient. I agree that in most cases, WebClient is OK, and actually better than HttpWebRequest because it's simpler to use, but in some cases you're better off using HttpWebRequest

Comment: Using HttpWebRequest you can define a timeout. In WebClient, that's impossible.

Comment: @ripper234, actually it *is* possible: you just have to inherit WebClient and override GetWebRequest to customize the HttpWebRequest

Comment: Hmm, interesting - I never thought of that!

Comment: @ThomasLevesque if you are inheriting webclient and overriding the webrequest, it seems pointless to use the webclient...

Comment: @HagaiL, I disagree... You don't have to create the whole request manually, you can use `base.GetWebRequest` to create it and then customize just what you want

Answer (score 57):

`HttpWebRequest` exposes a lot more stuff that allows you fine grained protocol control, for eg: whether you want to use Keep-Alive, what connection pool to use, whether to buffer writes or not, etc.

`WebClient` does not expose all of those (although you can subclass from `WebClient` and getaccess to the underlying Request object).

`WebClient` is useful for those situations where you just want to do an operation (eg: POST/GET/Form upload) and cant be bothered to create and manage the `HttpWebRequest`, `RequestStream`, `HttpWebResponse`, and response stream.

Comment: Also, there is one more thing that I forgot to mention. WebClient is a Component object, whereas HttpWebRequest is not. What does that mean?

Well, if you are using VisualStudio to build a GUI app, then you can drag/drop WebClient component on your form and use it to issue requests to HTTP/FTP etc servers.

Answer (score 14):

From Tim Heuer's blog - http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/calling-web-services-with-silverlight-2.aspx

Instead in Silverlight you'll want to use WebClient or HttpWebRequest.  What's the difference?  Here's the timheuer version.  WebClient is a simpler implementation doing GET requests really easily and get a response stream.  HttpWebRequest is great for when you need a bit more granular control over the request, need to send headers or other customizations.

Comment: WebClient also allows POST, with UploadString, UploadData and UploadFile

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Is there a newer version of the classes today? I see that this discussion is a bit, hmm... aged...

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I don't think there's been much change to the WebClient class. For new apps I suggest you use HttpClient instead, which is also very easy to use and much more flexible.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Right, **that** was the one I was thinking about. I recalled *http* as the difference in the class name and got mislead by *Http...* part. Now I'm back on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The *WebClient* class runs on the user interface thread, so the user interface is not responsive while data is being downloaded from the Internet. On the other hand, the *HttpWebRequest* class does not block the user interface thread, and your application is responsive. 
So, in apps where a large amount of data is to be downloaded from the Internet or if the source of the data is slow to access, you should use the HttpWebRequest class; in all other cases, you should use the WebClient class.

Comment: The opposite is true on WP7. HttpWebRequest marshals back to the UI thread in Mango, causing me no end of grief right now. Grrr

Comment: WebClient supports asynchronous methods as well.

Answer (score 6):

Another disadvantage of `WebClient` is it ignores the HTTP `ContentType`'s `charset` value when you use it to get the response text. You have to explicitly set the encoding via the `Encoding` property.

Comment: This is a good point; and it's not just a matter of setting the `Encoding` - you can't *know* the encoding until after the request, so the WebClient api  makes it very unlikely you're going to be able to properly download a string in an unknown encoding.

Answer (score 5):

One more thing HttpWebrquest allows you compression but he Net.WebClient class doesn't support HTTP compression

Comment: Just like all the other examples of WebClient hiding some details, this can be fixed by subclassing WebClient and overriding `GetWebRequest`. In this case, you simply [tweak the underlying `HttpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompressiong` property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914874/48700)).

Answer (score 5):

The "HtttpWebRequest" is obsolete in .NET 4.5. Now, this class is internal only.

Comment: Indeed. Use `WebRequest` instead.

Comment: The class is not obsolete, the constructors are. And the class is not internal, it is still public.

Answer (score 2):

One example: Posting data and getting back processed data in one request/response cycle seems to be impossible with WebClient, but you can do that with HtttpWebRequest.

Comment: Simply use WebClient.UploadString or WebClient.UploadData to perform a POST and get back a response string or byte array.

Comment: To clarify, the return value of the UploadString is a string and the return value of the UploadData method is a byte array.