# HttpWebRequest Vs webclient class who is better

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebClient vs. HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694388/webclient-vs-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse)

I can't guess who is better

[HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or  [webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Can you suggest me which one is better in terms of performance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd recommend testing the performance w/ what you want to do in both instances. I believe though that WebClient is simply a helper that implements HttpWebRequest under the hood.