# Squid: forward to another proxy (with authentication details for the parent proxy)

Tags: authentication, proxy

**In short, I am looking for a simple way to do the following** (please give code samples if possible):

- set up and start a proxy server on my computer (say address is 10.10.200.200:6767) that can capture all web requests from my phone
- once the request from phone comes to this proxy, it will add custom authentication details (my_username/my_password) and forward it to the institute proxy (say address is 10.1.2.3:80)
- I dont need any caching/acceleration on my local proxy (10.10.200.200). It just needs to catch the request and forward it.

**Now, more details to fully explain my situation:**

In my institute, authentication is needed to pass through a proxy so that we can connect to the internet. I normally enter my ldap username/password to authenticate when the pop up appears.

Now, I want to connect my phone to the institute WiFi but my phone does not have the option of authentication with proxy. Only a proxy address can be specified. So, I am planning to set up a local proxy on my computer to catch all requests from my phone, add authentication details and pass it to my institute proxy through my computer.

**I installed squid3 (on Ubuntu), but looking at the configuration file, I am lost. I tried googling but it looks all too complicated.**

Hoping someone can provide help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I figured from squid tutorials that the simplest configuration to do this is:

```
http_access allow all
http_port 3128

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320

cache_peer 10.1.2.3 parent 80 0 no-query default login=my_username:my_password
never_direct allow all
```

These lines should get you a working proxy server on your local machine that forwards all requests to another proxy server (change ip addresses accordingly). **However, please note** that in the above script, I have disabled any access control/filters, so potentially, anybody can connect and use your proxy. You need to add additional code to restrict entry to only some devices.

Comment: I needed to add the following:
```
access_log none
cache_log none
```

Comment: FTR: to limit the access to your only host, comment out the `http_access allow all` line, and append at the end the three lines: `acl allowed_ip src localhost`, `http_access allow allowed_ip`, `http_access deny all` *(yes, `deny all` have to be in the end, no idea why)*. And for the safe case: no, one can't check whether it worked with netcat from another host, only with something working by http *(squid would not deny tcp, only http)*.