# Lightweight forwarding proxy with auth support

Tags: http, proxy

I have an application that is running on a server behind a proxy. The proxy needs authentication, but my application is not able to supply proxy authentication. 
I'm now looking for a leightweight proxy that I can run on localhost, and forwards all http requests via the http-proxy. My localhost proxy must supply the authentication for the remote proxy.

I tried privoxy but it doesnt support authentication against the parent-proxy. Squid seems to be overkill. Any suggestions?

Comment: nginx can be used as a great lightweight proxy that should be able to handle authentication

Comment: what kind of auth the proxy have?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, what kind of different proxy-authentications there are. I simply pass a user/password combo like this: export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy:8080"

Comment: @ThomasM. if the proxy have NTLM auth then you must look for a third partie program to authenticate, like CNTLM. This kind of auth is very problematic. You are using Linux ?

Comment: How can I check which kind of authentication the proxy has? I tried cntlm, but it didn't work - I assumed, because the proxy is not using NTLM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use squid, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19219509/2015768

`http_access allow all
http_port 3128
access_log none
cache_log none
never_direct allow all
cache_peer   proxy.acme.corp   parent   8080   0  no-query default login=username:password`

Comment: Squid is heavyweight caching proxy, and TS exlpicitly mentioioned it.

Comment: What is "heavy" and what is "light" depends on the eye of the beholder. Given that the OP mentioned privoxy, squid might still be considered as "light".  The proposed solution fulfills the "can authenticate against the parent proxy" requirement which seems what OP wanted to achieve.