# How to use proxy with authentication in headless chorme browser using selenium and python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, proxy

I have used DesiredCapabilities

```
capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
capabilities['proxy'] = {'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
                         'httpProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'ftpProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'sslProxy': proxy['address'],
                         'noProxy': '',
                         'class': "org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
                         'autodetect': False
                         }
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
```

But nothing happen, where if I remove headless I get to see Authentication required alert.

I have also used

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s:%s@%s:%s'%(Config.PROXY_USERNAME,Config.PROXY_PASSWORD,Config.PROXY_URL,Config.PROXY_PORT))
```

But this did not help. Where I have changed "http" to "socks","socks4" and "socks5" where this didn't help even.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, username and password is also there with DesiredCapabilities

proxy = {'address': '%s:%s'%(Config.PROXY_URL,Config.PROXY_PORT),
             'username': Config.PROXY_USERNAME,
             'password': Config.PROXY_PASSWORD}
capabilities['proxy']['socksUsername'] = proxy['username']
capabilities['proxy']['socksPassword'] = proxy['password']

Comment: Update the question with this information for a better analysis.

Comment: i am facing this issue. @MohitTamta are there updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, headless chrome discards alerts ([Issue 718235](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718235)) and extensions are not supported ([Issue 706008](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706008#c5)) so we can't use the tricks which work in GUI mode. This leaves us with two main options:

### Option 1 - Proxy redirect

Run a separate proxy without authentication and redirect it to the target proxy with authentication.

You can do it in one line with [**mitmproxy**](https://mitmproxy.org/):
`mitmproxy --mode  upstream:http://<target-proxy-ip>:<target-proxy-port> --upstream-auth  <user>:<password> -p 3128` and configure your client to use `localhost:3128` as a proxy.

> You can install mitmproxy via pip:   `pip install mitmproxy` (requires
>   python3)
>   **Reference:**  https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/

Or with **[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org)** proxy: [Squid: forward to another proxy (with authentication details for the parent proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199424/squid-forward-to-another-proxy-with-authentication-details-for-the-parent-prox)

### Option 2 - Use Xvfb display server

> Xvfb performs all graphical operations in virtual memory without
>   showing any screen output
>   **Reference:** https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml

Here is the instruction for using it with Selenium: [How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb)
Python wrapper for Xvfb: https://github.com/ponty/pyvirtualdisplay

Good luck!