# PowerShell SSL/TLS error with Invoke-RestMethod command

Tags: powershell, ssl

I am trying to access Foreman API in Powershell version 5.1 using Invoke-RestMethod

I get following error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I tried following command before the this command but it didn't work.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

I tried with Tls, Tls11 also but it didn't work.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting to an untrusted SSL certificate by any chance?
You probably need to ignore trust errors as well as set the correct TLS version to use.

```
Add-Type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I am getting a different error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: Any chance that you are trying to connect via a Proxy Server? 
If so, try running this as soon as you open a new PowerShell session, then try the Invoke. [Access web using Powershell and Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263359/access-web-using-powershell-and-proxy)

Comment: The same code is working with Powershell Core 6 with -SkipCertificateCheck parameter.