# Windows Powershell policy execution bypass

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have been creating a powershell script to help me automate tasks across various user's PCs, I've encountered an issue where I have to manually allow scripts to run on each PC before I can execute it.

I have attempted to use various solutions that I have found but so far none seem to work.

Solutions I have tried as a batch file (Ideally I would like to have the batch file download the script (sorted this already) then open the powershell script and successfully bypass this):

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -nologo -file "multitool.ps1"
```

---

```
powershell -command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force}"
```

---

```
    @echo off
reg add HKLM\system32\windows\microsoft\powershell\1\shellids\microsoft.powershell /v "Path" /d "c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
reg add HKLM\system32\windows\microsoft\powershell\1\shellids\microsoft.powershell /v "ExecutionPolicy" /d "unrestricted"
```

---

```
@echo off
regedit /s file.reg
```

Where file.reg contains the following:

```
[hkey_local_machine\system32\windows\microsoft\powershell\1\shellids\microsoft.powershell] 
"Path"="c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
"ExecutionPolicy"="unrestricted"
```

All of these result in the following when running the powershell script: [image: screen shot]

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: In order to permanently change the execution policy, you need to run your powershell or registry change elevated, i.e Run as administrator. Additionally, you may have to modify your Windows setting which is likely to have marked your downloaded file as unsafe, this is a common marker attributed to executable downloaded files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closest solution I've found for this is running the following line in powershell as admin which will execute the script and bypass the restrictions:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted C:\multitool.ps1
```

If anyone has a cleaner solution that can run the script from the bat file I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In essence, this is no different from the first command in your question, so if this command works, so does the one in the question. As explained, only GPO-based execution policies could thwart this approach. (The only difference is that `Bypass` _never_ restricts script execution, whereas `Unrestricted`, despite its name, will prompt you to confirm the intent to execute scripts downloaded from the internet.)

Comment: @K4STRL I am doing the suggested code but the location of the script has a space in it. Powershell stops at C:\Folder and doesn't to go C:\Folder Space\. I have put that location in "" but it does the same thing. What else can I do to get the script to run?

Answer (score 6):

**`powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass ...` is the right approach *in principle* for an ad-hoc policy override**, but as the conceptual help topic that the error message points to, [about_Execution_Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies), states, **if execution policies are set *via Group Policy*** (rather than via [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy)), **they *cannot be overridden* through other means, including on the command line**:

From the [Use Group Policy to Manage Execution Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies?view=powershell-7.2#use-group-policy-to-manage-execution-policy) section (emphasis added):

> You can use the `Turn on Script Execution` Group Policy setting to manage the execution policy of computers in your enterprise. *The Group Policy setting overrides the execution policies set in PowerShell in all scopes.*

See also: [About Group Policy Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_group_policy_settings?view=powershell-5.1) (Windows PowerShell) and [About Group Policy Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_group_policy_settings) (PowerShell (Core) 7+), which discusses the **relevant Group Policy settings** in detail.

Answer (score 4):

Try running this code, it helped me with same problem

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 2):

To temporarily bypass the execution policy and run a PowerShell script, do either of the following:

1. Temporarily set the Bypass Execution Policy. This will set the execution policy
   to “Bypass” for the current user during the session, allowing you to run
   multiple scripts without restrictions in the current session.

- Open a PowerShell window as an Administrator.
- Execute the following command: Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process

*OR*

2. Run a Single Script with the Bypass Policy. If you need to execute an unsigned
   script that doesn’t adhere to the current session's execution policy, use the
   following command:

- powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Path\To\YourScript.ps1
- Script shorthand: powershell -ep Bypass C:\Path\To\YourScript.ps1

Answer (score 0):

Write this in an open powershell window with admin rights:

> set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy remotesigned

then run the script with:

> .\your script.ps1