# Trouble with ExecutionPolicy when running Powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, batch-file, executionpolicy

I am trying to write a Powershell script to automate general tasks on a new computer including installing software. ExecutionPolicy has been the bane of my existence when it comes to blocking me from running automated scripts that I have been writing.

One of my PS scripts requires elevated Admin privileges, so I have a batch file where I am calling to launch PS as Administrator but I am still getting stuck with the script instantly closing/failing due to ExecutionPolicy. Ideally, I would like a way to bypass the ExecutionPolicy on a per script basis instead of completely changing it and then changing it back.

I have looked up different Set-ExecutionPolicy methods but they don't seem to work.

I need a generic command in a .bat file to launch a specified powershell script as Admin AND bypassing the current ExecutionPolicy.

Comment: Bypass is your answer. Either that, or sign your scripts. Unless you want to unrestrict all

Comment: You know there is a command line argument for the execution policy for the PowerShell executable, don't you?  You may run `PowerShell /?` to read more about. ;-)

Comment: I'm curious what happens when you load the ps1 script as ScriptBlock and execute it there.  Seems I read someplace there are fewer restrictions on code ran in a ScriptBlock.

Comment: @Darin, scratch my last comment - I misread yours. You are correct: Execution policies only relate to script _files_, so reading a file's _content_ into memory and executing that - be it via constructing a script block first or by passing it directly to the usually-to-be-avoided `Invoke-Expression` - is a way to bypass the active execution policy. That said, the technique won't work if the code executed this way calls _other_ script files, which may also happen _implicitly_  when modules are auto-imported.

Comment: @mklement0, I knew my comment had at least some validity independent of your confirmation, which is why I just let it slide.  But I do appreciate you letting me know what you found out.  The particular command I've been working on, and works so far in my situation, is powershell with RemoteSigned (If I hit a wall someday, I may have to switch to bypass).  In the command there is prep of several variables, including flags indicating the batch is in pipe or called from GUI, and then a scriptblock wrapped around a scriptblock of a file with the batch parameter line. 437 chars not counting indent

Comment: Thanks, @Darin. On a meta note, while I understand that it's easier and sometimes even better to let things slide, I am always happy to correct my mistakes (which may involve simple deleting comments that were based on a misconception), so if you're up for it, tell me - sometimes both parties learn in the process. As for your technique: I don't fully understand (it's fine), but let me make one more general point: Unless GPOs control your execution policy, the `-ExecutionPolicy` CLI parameter works and requires no workarounds. Otherwise, the limitations stated in my previous comment apply.

Comment: @mklement0, to partly remedy "I don't fully understand", you need to understand the goal.  Single design for a batch file that calls ps1 file, accepts pipeline input that is passed to ps1 file, can recognize it has either been double clicked or files dragged-N-dropped on it - and ps1 files can detect this, passes the command line as is for PowerShell to process, and doesn't have execution issues that ps1 file have.   I think I achieved this goal about 2 weeks ago, with the possible exception of execution policy.  I think I need to sit down and really get my head wrapped around it.

Answer (score 2):

> I need a generic command in a .bat file to launch a specified powershell script as Admin AND bypassing the current ExecutionPolicy.

The key is to **use the `-ExecutionPolicy` [*CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) parameter** (which only the *inner* `powershell` call below needs; the sole purpose of the *outer* one is to launch the target session *with elevation* (as admin), which itself doesn't involve execution of a *script* file):

- *Caveat*: If your effective execution policy is controlled by *GPOs* (Group Policy Objects), it can *not* be overridden<sup>[1]</sup> - neither with the `-ExecutionPolicy` CLI parameter, nor in-session with `Set-ExecutionPolicy` - the solution below won't work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67270549/45375) for details.

Also - unrelated to execution policies - **additional work is required in order to preserve the caller's *working directory***, because ***elevated* sessions default to the SYSTEM32 directory**. Therefore, the command below incorporates an explicit `Set-Location` call to set the working directory. Note that in order to call a script located in that directory you need to prefix its name with `.\` (e.g., `.\script.ps1` instead of just `script.ps1`):

```
:: Run from cmd.exe / a batch file.
:: The target script file is '.\script.ps1' in this example, and
:: 'foo 1' and 'bar' are sample arguments to pass to it.
powershell -noprofile -c Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell '-noexit -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -c Set-Location -LiteralPath ''%CD:'=''''%''; ^& .\script.ps1 ''foo 1'' bar'
```

<sup>`-noexit` keeps the elevated session open after the specified `.ps1` script terminates; remove it, if you want the session and thereby its window to close automatically.

`-noprofile` suppresses loading of the profile scripts; in the *second* `powershell` call, that isn't strictly necessary, but still advisable for a predictable execution environment.</sup>

Note:

- In order to avoid `"`-related escaping hell, the above solution uses `'...'` strings only, as understood by PowerShell in the context of a `-c` (`-Command`) [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) call, which, however, assumes the following:

  - The script file name / path itself and the pass-through arguments mustn't contain `'` chars. - if they do, they must be enclosed in `''....''` and the *embedded* `'` must be escaped as `''''` (sic).

    - For the `Set-Location` call above, this is handled *automatically* by using `cmd.exe`'s string-replacement technique on its `%CD%` variable (`%CD:'=''''%`).
  - If the script file path or pass-through arguments contain *spaces*, there mustn't be runs of *multiple* spaces - if so (which would be very unusual in the case of paths), `"`-quoting would have to be used. Otherwise, values with spaces must be enclosed in `''...''`, as shown with the `foo 1` argument above.
  - Since the script file is invoked via `-c` (`-Command`) rather than via `-f` (`-File`), the interpretation of arguments passed to it may situationally differ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458726/45375).

---

<sup>[1] There is a *limited* workaround: Execution policies only relate to script *files*, so reading a script file's *content* into memory and executing that - be it via constructing a script block first or by passing it directly to the usually-to-be-avoided `Invoke-Expression` - is a way to bypass the active execution policy. A simplified example: 
`powershell -noprofile -c "Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Raw c:\path\to\foo.ps1)"`. That said, the technique won't work if the code executed this way calls *other* script files, which may also happen *implicitly*  when modules are auto-imported.</sup>