# Windows Task Scheduler - Copy file from URL to Desktop

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm wanting to create an automated job in Windows (presumably using Task Scheduler) to copy a CSV file from a URL to my desktop. From what I can gather, a batch file cannot copy a file from an external location. Not familiar with Powershell, but it looks like it might have that capability.

What is the best way to create a script and automate the process to copy a file (http://example.com/file.csv) to my Desktop for instance? Would like to use features native to Windows without having to download a third-party application if possible.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973880/download-url-content for an example using WebClient to download the file in powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download a file using powershell using syntax like this:

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile("http://example.com/file.csv","C:\tmp\file.txt")
```

Save this as a script (something.ps1). Then create a task in the Task Scheduler and add a new "Action" of the type Open Program. Use program `PowerShell`, and specify the path to the script (like C:\something.ps1) as the argument.

More info:

- [How to download files using powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing)
- [Scheduling Powershell script execution](http://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/004_SharePointActions/012_SchedulingPowerShell.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Scripting Host does allow you to get files via HTTP.

See AnthonyWJones' answer at [HTTP GET in VBS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204759/http-get-in-vbs)

Change code as appropriate, save as .vbs file, schedule same.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about powershell so I don't know if it can do it. I know you prefer not to use a third-party application, but you can easily do what you want with curl which comes as a single stand-alone exe: http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/