# Automatically decompress gzip response via WebClient.DownloadData

Tags: .net, gzip, webclient

I wish to automatically uncompress GZiped response.
I am using the following snippet:

```
mywebclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
mywebclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

try
{
    var resp = mywebclient.DownloadData(someUrl);
}
```

I have checked `HttpRequestHeader enum`, and there is no option to do this via the `Headers`

How can I automatically decompress the resp? or Is there another function I should use instead of `mywebclient.DownloadData` ?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

WebClient uses HttpWebRequest under the covers. And HttpWebRequest supports gzip/deflate decompression. See [HttpWebRequest AutomaticDecompression property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression.aspx)

However, WebClient class does not expose this property directly. So you will have to derive from it to set the property on the underlying HttpWebRequest.

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use the "excessively used" (IMHO) as-casting instead of "traditional casting" here? If you use as, you should definitely check that request is non-null, so I wonder if it wouldn't just be simpler in this case to assume that the result from GetWebRequest() is always an HttpWebRequest...

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for a WP8.1 Silverlight project. the property "AutomaticDecompression" is not available. Any ideas what I should do? Thanks!

Comment: It can help to also add | DecompressionMethods.Brotli if the encoding is "br".

Answer (score 32):

Depending on your situation, it may be simpler to do the decompression yourself.

```
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Net;

try
{
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
    var responseStream = new GZipStream(client.OpenRead(myUrl), CompressionMode.Decompress);
    var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    var textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // do stuff

}
```

I created all the temporary variables for clarity.  This can all be flattened to only `client` and `textResponse`.

Or, if simplicity is the goal, you could even do this using [ServiceStack.Text by Demis Bellot](http://www.servicestack.net/):

```
using ServiceStack.Text;

var resp = "some url".GetJsonFromUrl();
```

(There are other `.Get*FromUrl` extension methods)

Comment: I'm not sure client.OpenRead respects encoding set for webClient instance

Comment: A caveat to point out: you must actually _read_ the gzip stream in order for it to uncompress; attempting to be clever with something like `responseStream.CopyTo( File.OpenWrite(...) )` doesn't work