# Can't read httpwebresponse

Tags: c#, vb.net, encoding, httpwebresponse

I am getting a invalidoperation exception when I try to Deserialize a webresponse.

In this webresponse I get an XML page which send over https.
What my code does is basically send a webrequest to get login-cookies, then another request to get an XML page, afterwards i deserialize that page.

The problem occurs when I try to deserialize, it gives me the following error:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
```

First I looked into my webresponse to see if it has proper data. So I put my webresponse into the streamreader and used readToEnd to convert it into string. Like so:

```
dim myStringResult as String = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

It gave me some letters numbers and blocks. So I think the response I get is the problem. I checked it out with Fiddler and saw that the response needed to be decoded before I could see the content(and yes it did have the proper response I wanted). I went a little deeper into the exception and saw it says

```
hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1
```

I tried looking into the System.Text.Encoding, but couldn't find anything for hexadecimal.
Can anyone help me with this?

edit: It's possible that I have to decode it because it is a https response and not because it's hexadecimal encoded.

edit1: I have tried `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` unfortunately it didnt change the string.

edit2:  example of data i am getting

> {� �U�r�0��+(g���(J��ԙ$�k;IomR& �I�N?���/� 6���L�^`���

it doesn't show the data right. It suppose to be mostly squars. Every now and then you see

edit: the header

> ```
> content-disposition: : attachment; filename="document.xml"
> CachingModuleShouldWork: true
> Content-Language: en-US
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
> ```
>
> Content-Length: 382 Content-Type: application/xml

Comment: Can you post an example of the data you're getting back from your http response?

Comment: I editted my question. It's really weird that nothing changes. I have done what you asked. Is it because the response is in https and thats why it gave out that 0x1f error?

Comment: What the heck is that?  What are you receiving via the HttpResponse?  I was expecting and Xml document... That looks like it's some sort of binary output.

Comment: exactly, this is my problem - When I used fiddler I can't see it in the textview, but when I right click the response and then use "Decode selected Session" then it will show me the xml. This is what I meant with the response giving me letters, numbers and blocks. I am not entirely sure it is because of https, but fiddler does show if I "Decode" the session that I get to see my xml-document.

Comment: Can you post the content type header for your webresponse (should be in fiddler)

Comment: @FasterSolutions  added them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x1f is a Windows control character. It is not valid XML.

You need to decode it first using something like [HttpUtility.Decode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

So:   get your response and read it into a string using a StreamReader then do something like:

```
StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter();
         // Decode the encoded string.
         HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(myEncodedString, myWriter);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I put my streamreader into string and did it like you said. It still gives me weird characters and all of that weird stuff in the "myWriter".

Comment: The string just stayed the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you're decoding content read from the web I recommend you to check this:

[HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx)

**EDIT: Similar question**

[hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728329/hexadecimal-value-0x1f-is-an-invalid-character-line-1-position-1)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work,  I put my streamreader into string and did it like you said. It still gives me weird characters and all of that weird stuff in the "myWriter".