# hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, restsharp, jql

I am getting some odd inconsistent results. This web method was working fine earlier. I had only added some UI stuff (jquery-ui and twitter-bootstrap). I tried removing all that UI stuff, but I still get this error. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the JIRA server or if I'm not creating my requests correctly.

I've tried doing the following ([based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728329/hexadecimal-value-0x1f-is-an-invalid-character-line-1-position-1)):

- use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`
- `textVar = textVar.Replace((char)(0x1F), ' ').Trim();`

However, neither have worked.

This code doesn't throw an exception, but he `var response` in the C# code has this error stack trace. Output:

```
RestSharp response status: Error -
 HTTP response: Forbidden -
 Forbidden -
 '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1. -
 System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text)
   at RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer.Deserialize[T](IRestResponse response)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.Deserialize[T](IRestRequest request, IRestResponse raw) -
```

The empty quote `''` is actually some other character that looks similar to: `[US]`. Is there something I can do to fix this or does this seem to be a JIRA sever issue?

My minimized example:

```
private static string serverUrl = "https://www.url.com/jira";
private static string baseUrl = "/rest/api/2/";
private static string searchCommand = "search";

public static void QuickTest()
{
    string username = HttpContext.Current.Session["jira_username"].ToString();
    string pw = HttpContext.Current.Session["jira_password"].ToString();

    //also tried hardcoding these values. didn't work either
    //username = "";
    //pw = "";

    //create client     
    RestClient client = new RestClient(serverUrl)
    {
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, pw)
    };
    //create query
    string jql = "assignee=msalim";
    //string jql = "assignee%3Dmsalim"; //didn't work either

    //create request
    var request = new RestRequest();
    request.Resource = Path.Combine(baseUrl, searchCommand);
    request.AddParameter(new RestSharp.Parameter()
    {
        Name = "jql",
        Value = jql,
        Type = ParameterType.GetOrPost
    });

    request.Method = Method.GET;

    //get response
    var response = client.Execute<Issues>(request);
    string errorMessage = string.Format("RestSharp response status: {0} -\n HTTP response: {1} -\n {2} -\n {3} -\n {4} -\n ", response.ResponseStatus, response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription, response.ErrorMessage, response.ErrorException);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errorMessage);
}
```

Also, I've tried entering both of these in my Firefox browser and they return the expected results:

```
https://www.url.com/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee%3Dmsalim

https://www.url.com/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=msalim
```

Comment: You need to see actual response to figure out what is going wrong - i.e. use Fiddler to capture... Note that you should be able to do that from command line app too and don't need any JavaScript in your post (you may also simplify C# sample to use constant Url).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've simplified the code. Did you mean to check the response's request after executing?

Comment: Instead of deserializing directly to an `Issues` object, have you tried `client.Execute(request)` to see the raw content?  Or is that where you did the replace earlier?

Comment: @pilotcam That just gives me the same error with less info. The `Content` is always an unreadable string.

Comment: Incidentally, wouldn't you want to use Url.Combine instead of Path.Combine?  Is it possible your request path is invalid?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc - yes, service response. I assume you've managed to run request manually and see response (probably HTML with "come again another day" sort of text), but if you could not - setting process' proxy to Fiddler localhost:8888 would let you capture most complicated request/response pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19716736/2498729) led me to the problem. I tried a coworker's login and password for JIRA and it worked perfectly. The server under `serverUrl` had banned me from logging in again because I had made so many requests. Now I have to communicate with server admin to figure this out. Another thing to note is that each request I made counted as a "failed login" according to JIRA.