# Webclient slow at startup

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, download, webclient

Here is the downloading time when I click update button:

- First time = 5 sec
- After first time = 2 sec

Why it takes more time at first time? Without `wc.Proxy = null;` it took 2 minute at first time, is there anything else that slow it down?

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Proxy = null;
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0");
    wc.DownloadFile("http://example.com/folder/file.txt",@"folder/files/file.txt");
}
sw.Stop();
```

Comment: Could it be the web server takes some time to process the first request, but after it has some of your data cached and can respond more quickly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebClient is very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988981/webclient-is-very-slow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution to **speed-up this process is caching**. If the nature of the files/data that you are downloading is static, it is better to cache them on your web/app server.

Another solution would be firing the downloading process in a **different UI thread**, and possibility to use asynchronous process to free up your UI thread, to avoid freezing the application UI.

Here you are some references that might be helpful:

- [UI Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647051.aspx)
- [Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4428817/1437962)
- [Threading - UI locking up](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/4caf2554-61e6-4dd1-b493-dadd74178703)