# WCF first webservice call from client to server takes approx 22 sec

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

Just a small summary of the infrastructure. I have a webservice running on a server in India only accessible through the companies internal network. I'm located in Europe.
The webservice is hosted in its own windows service, so no IIS.
When starting the client the first call allways takes approx 22 sec., this is a simple "ping" operation, just asking if the server is there, so no logic on the server that takes any time.

I have tried this solution [First call to a .net webservice is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086045/first-call-to-a-net-webservice-is-slow) with a bypass list. But that doesn't seem to work, unless it's me doing something wrong ?

```
  <bypasslist>
    <add address="[a-z]+\.company_name\.com"/>
  </bypasslist>
```

Where the server address is `staging.company_name.com`

I also tried the other solution that has been suggested in the post, but still no luck.

```
<configuration >
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Using fiddler I can see that the above apparently works, because this results in fiddler not being able to capture the traffic.
All the following webservice calls on the client are handled within short time less than 1 sec.

What / How can I reduce the first calls delay ?

**UPDATE**

This wasn't due to problems with WCF this is a routing / DNS problem on our network in the company....

Comment: Are you using NTLM authentication?

Comment: An authentication handshake could take some time I guess. You should check the communication with Wireshark.

Comment: The first call is making use of a simple basicHttpBinding without any authentication.