# Fiddler speeds up HTTPClients Requests even without Reuse Connections option

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-4.5, fiddler

my App uses the .NET 4.5 HTTPClient sending Keep Alive header over this:

```
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "true");
```

By far, the HttpClient just worked and the speed was ok, but I recently discovered in a test program(it sends as much request as possible over multiple threads to a https server and outputs the requests per second rate to test performance)that its around 3 times faster when fiddler is running, even without the reuse connection option(no difference).
I researched about this topic, but there were only hints pointing to the keep-alive header&reuse connection option, so my question is: *Whats the point fiddler speed ups the app and what I`ll have to change in my code to make the requests faster.*

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

*(pls add a comment if there are more informations needed)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I just got the error after looking up to the similiar webclient: so if you have probs like me, just add a `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 300; // or sth` before you re doing request in your code.

[WebClient is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988981/webclient-is-very-slow)