# Retrieve Json data with HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, microsoft-metro

I am programming for Visual Studio 2011 so I am forced to use `HttpClient`. I need to retrieve some JSON data from the web, but I guess I need to set the content to "json data" or something  because I always get strange characters when using only this code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.Get("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users");
var content = response.Content.ReadAsString();
```

So how can I set the content or what should I do to get the correct data ?

edit:

Output: something like this: ������

Comment: Why does that "force" you to use HttpClient?

Comment: There is no such thing as Visual Studio 2011. Do you mean Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview? And no version of Visual Studio forces you to use `HttpClient`. What exactly do you mean by that? Are you developing a Metro-style app?

Comment: I guess he is working on a Metro style application and there's no longer a `WebClient` class in `WinRT`.

Comment: I think you can still use `WebRequest`. Also, I think the problem is that `HttpClient` doesn't automatically decompress gzipped data.

Comment: I can use WebRequest too, but I find it much complicated (I have to use BeginGetResponse() witch is asynchronous).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that the response is compressed and `HttpClient` does not automatically decompress it by default.

With `WebClient`, you can [create a derived class and set the `AutomaticDecompression` of the underlying `HttpWebRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914874/41071).

You can't do that with `HttpClient`, because it doesn't have any suitable `virtual` methods. But you can do it by passing [`HttpClientHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to its constructor:

```
var client =
    new HttpClient(
        new HttpClientHandler
        {
            AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip
                                     | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
        });
```

Comment: very helpful after hours of searching about wrong characters in response. I first thought that it is due to encoding! but it was gzip!