.NET Web Scraping works in Console Application but not in Api Application
I want to get the html content result from a search executed on amazon (e.g. Example link).

My applications runs on localhost.
When I start an .NET Console Application the result ist correct (html code)
When I start from .NET API Application the result is useless (see below)

In this case I use a react app in the browser which calls the api, which performs the scraping



string url = ProductHttpClient.GetProductSearchUrl(searchTerm);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", "i18n-prefs=EUR;");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

\u001f�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0�t��j�@\fE��\ne6�\t��E�Igf�\u000f(��\"<�\v{lf�$�||��6P��\u0005�#�Az�B>G�Z���9�#_\u0019�\u0018\u001d+(:��(B?...
Please notice again:

Exactly the same code is executed
I always get an Status 200

How is this possible and how can I solve this problem?

this looks like your response is gzip compressed, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939980/strange-httpclient-result

Thank yes this works even if I don’t understand why the result is zipped when I start via API
