# C# WebClient DownloadString returns gibberish

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

I am attempting to view the source of http://simpledesktops.com/browse/desktops/2012/may/17/where-the-wild-things-are/ using the code:

```
String URL = "http://simpledesktops.com/browse/desktops/2012/may/17/where-the-wild-things-are/";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1255");

string download = webClient.DownloadString(URL);

webClient.Dispose();

Console.WriteLine(download);
```

When I run this, the console returns a bunch of nonsense that looks like it's been decoded incorrectly.

I've also attempted adding headers with no avail:

```
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.9.2.4) Gecko/20100611 Firefox/3.6.4");    
webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
```

Other websites all returned the proper html source. I can also view the page's source through Chrome. What's going on here?

Comment: Response is gzipped, you should decompress it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata

Comment: How do you know that the response is Windows-1255?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response of that URL is gzipped, you should decompress it or set empty Accept-Encoding header, you don't need that user-agent field.

```
  String URL = "http://simpledesktops.com/browse/desktops/2012/may/17/where-the-wild-things-are/";    
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();    
  webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "");
  string download = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same thing bug me today.

Using a WebClient object to check whether a URL is returning something.

But my experience is different. I tried removing the Accept-Encoding, basically using the code @Antonio Bakula gave in his answer. But I kept getting the same error every time (InvalidOperationException)

So this did not work:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "");
string result = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

But adding 'any' text as a User Agent instead did do the trick. This worked fine:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "My User Agent String");
System.IO.Stream stream = wc.OpenRead(url);
```

Your mileage may vary obviously, also of note. I'm using ASP.NET 4.0.30319.