# Bad text file after download it

Tags: c#, download, webclient

When I try download text file, I get bad text like `"úěćË¨Të€Ás…­žVż$—éxś¶źŹßCb}ă¬–92á•,˝V....."`

I use WebClient class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient _WebClient = new WebClient();
    string url = "http://bossa.pl/pub/metastock/forex/sesjafx/";
    string file= "20120601.prn";
    _WebClient.DownloadFile(url + file, @"C:\"+file);
}
```

There is not problem with file `20120603.prn`, but with `20120601.prn` is.
What is going?

Comment: Are there only english letters in 20120603.prn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [Automatically decompress gzip response via WebClient.DownloadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata)

basically you have to enable automatic decompression of the webclient. If you examine the responseheaders (forexample by using firebug or fiddler)  for file 20120601.prn a gzip Content-Encoding is returned. For file 20120603.prn that Content-Encoding header is missing at all.

```
void Main()
{
    WebClient _WebClient = new MyWebClient(); 
    string url = "http://bossa.pl/pub/metastock/forex/sesjafx/"; 
    string file= "20120601.prn";
    string a = _WebClient.DownloadString(url + file); 
}

class MyWebClient : WebClient 
{ 
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) 
    { 
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest; 
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip; 
        return request; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this

```
client.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("your encoding");
```

Comment: If im not mistake your Encoding will be "ISO8859-2"

Answer (score 1):

set your encoding to UTF8

```
_WebClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```