# How to read html source from a HTTPS url

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack

i am trying to read the html source code of a https url in c# with the following code:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 string htmlString = w.DownloadString("https://www.targetUrl.com");
```

[image]

this doesn't work for me as i get encoded html string. I tried using HtmlAgilityPack but with no help.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);
```

Comment: What does this mean `this doesn't work for me as i get encoded html string`?

Comment: means its not work for HTTPS link as https://www.targetUrl.com

Comment: `WebClient.DownloadString` doesn't need to do anything special to download from a https address. What do you mean "encoded"? How do you know it's encoded? What does it look like?

Comment: We do not have crystal ball here. What do you expect? what do you see? What exception do you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That URL is returning a gzip compressed string. `WebClient` doesn't support this by default, so you'll want to go down to the underlying `HttpWebRequest` class instead. Blatant rip-off of  the answer by feroze over here - [Automatically decompress gzip response via WebClient.DownloadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata)

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes its also work for http://example.com url but not work with https://example.com

Comment: @kavitaverma then download the page with `WebClient.DownloadData` and decompress it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string htmlString = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: You should probably add some comment with your code to make it clear how is your answer relevant compared to the already accepted answer.