# Webclient.DownloadString inconsistent response

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm using webclient.DownloadString to retrieve content on a website. But the response is not consistent, and I cant figure out what kind of encoding or something the response is.

The same URL is used, and sometimes it returnes plain HTML (which is correct) and sometimes I get this return:

```
    "�\b\0\0\0\0\0\0�[�s�6���(w�8����˒:��ƞ:�'v���р$$2�H��l)����p�,�T�m�ؓJ8���\au��ɻ��/���M�>��0�8?FRSQ>Ǌrr}�>�]��@����\a��za�}E9}+!�MӨ�(����!��L�~�,)/��fZ);�#��������6Z���%D�\tvF���g��K}2�v\t��b�4�+�D�a�}�\\�L�<LR���=����4�cZ%�@�<�ٜ�Q�M��»J�a�]�z\tټ6�R�L��!�]'$.�i�+)9�\0��P����'M*�yCbo�٘�]�e���B����IƟ�ˋEty������뛣����5>���ω��\v��9�PJ\b�mWB)�7�p���F$�I�؋hkcI���d:�J2kfNJW�\t�;��t��%$̈́3��I��OR�ĦM̀�*c֖)�3'H�\f\")�E\fWl'�d�e�����(��F�����ӑR�<Y��U�,C��[}as��?��A\0�|a��K]§��+�+_*J\b�;#/t�K����>-����J�NU]Q���jWk���͵�d�y.��ڳ9�g^�G�hyH뷞��}d��h�0J��M�{3 �{���a��Y��?\v4���\"p���H�\a/���g�\a�ؤ�'�̛�|u�<��YitL\"��~��!Q����bo�2���SS�^P�3K��\0�\f�I�T'�ü��a}�RU>�=�H�C���>�W��-�}���ܴN��_�ǄP�7b�dr5AiÚ 9�$�Sk�90r�m�LS���'�z&�-�%&���L�����\n���D��7�Mn=X�e��e�GAϱ_�{vM��u͑�p�4PS�(2�$�\v���(_�X�x%�!t�&k\0��`>HV��QYu9�6�b��\t��0F8p���\t\a*+�mg�8�#\bJ�C��\n-p8�A��a�\a1�F\v�X�\"�2:�bb���#������|g��FV�a�$%u�\r�B\f8��#��R\vW��~�<�J��ho�`�~ȁ�4��4ox��,��ޠ-9X':������� �\aV謨?�y\0(�����<k�}���;\f�����4L�j���\\O�P����a�Pj��\0�lI��*!��Ǔx(At\v}���P\nB��� *t��\"��l\0+h�`������j����M��\v�m@��}D�l\0����)���,�$�I��0�__�i3��A�犁��0kT��q��v��:z�X��+����׺V�&$�;f�ߍʷ�',a��y�gՌ�4Z��c����?����QV��ao�Lްڈ}�S �\n\r�\bi�\n\n�B1U1�8/��\b��$�-�e�˜���+A�a�\v37��s뒘Ȳ,��/H�H�*�~C�Ppaͽ4W�W�lC��L����\">�Y\b؅ㅹ\tG��ɢK[�scD%\f�Q�\fK�x~��\a�3]l��ߨw�c:P�P�ے��!����V�/��|Q�S>c�K>\\(����v��{�Q\t'��>(qޥ�\f���f���_ܺxeO5�]�0��L+e鼗\v��=eS��D����\\�;V+\v�\\���)�1��3`�4\0SCfa��du���\\��a!hT���� d\a�,V\\�x��Vf;#�'�\b1���c��\f4U����.�.�hCV~K��\r�j�a\0Ë*�[�跋��\n�^O�\\�f����~�[�����J����|<y_Em\b�\",��[�y�Y���'mK�38��w�H;@z����;�0�9q���K�C]�`B��\n���u���۠���\v�JU\r6��\"H\f:�ޞ�\"k՝�N���+t�]bG�.�0 �����NzU�sߢwW{�W�![���_/+¹U˥-��˫ex����g��VQ�tʽ*��aӢa��\f� x��P�GW?�c��4�B���l�<;]�Ռa��y�~:sH2��Q�G=+N[���kO�5v�6��q8��J��nmS���U%!���]%��W2��'�ٳ-@�w�sR����W�g7�����*��A�^�i�]�\a?5�HQ��<���M��p�� �p�]~��\v?M��0�ⷼ/��֊�\\/Mx�HCi�4��=��8��\b��<Oip��X8|f�\"�#�Yk�m�d�8���&<`�����h���x���s�b4�,tޞ�ѷ�F/�$^W����1��t�.wVɵ,5�ҹg]�茈�� ���k�a�F�n)o��^3vʮT{d�{��O�b1��RN�牥���]�J�F�j���>z���~�h�����˃D��E]y��.�)D�(E,'=�n]�T\b-6�z��8:|�ww���q�:Q����afww�M\b�h����m�qA\b�j��\v&�@�҂-^��\b����:(��ѯ�0�C\f�|*�$\\@XrP�ׂ[V\\d/���� �]\n��\r����c�ϥ<iN��c���\v��kW`�[�Oo�pA�Ho�1�^=`�3Y^\v���t��U���ƅV�\\\n%�.G�#6Ma�x�Fkv����1u�4�w����dr��[r;S�O��']�&�N��hrtt�O���Do��G�W����H%q�y17鄤���fą��=�4.��P!�\vAT\bR�ʅ 2z(\a�={r�\f����u�qзR��[S�鰻����w�T-�v�m���Z[��Ӟe�x��\f�R��J5@�S���jP�\\�U��6��R�����Å�0�^���4�����G��� 骻�#@϶�\t�$\r}\"{)�{��&�+;d�'�i��)&52��4{7�|ܛ�h�#7'��3�E�M�=��>������.NP\v\t�D.^�%RJ��HH�����.+n��$���e� ��le?дhy(!q&{��,�7��R�З�b�Gj���8��f�¶m��u����7���l�{��;�Z⭉[I?9dR�6��w�$�ӭnww'���\fm�00��5Զ.0V>Od�\tpBf8!�'o�2�\t����=�uO�(��}��F�VͮM��Cz���l6�n��DWu���=�t\v�S��r>2rju�S�9O<k��/��<zjƣ�gf�-��J������x��-8��i�YuV]:L�������c�?�S��xJ�\"���q�U'�m�jça;vW�j�촱��tթJL��ݖm�v��v�V�J��GM��~\f��0OL�'}d5� �����%�_��'p��ҒA�K��-s�(��i�j����l��ʝ��0˖d~'��@m�S�ku!Wo��Ӵ'̽��=�e��2��0WS�j49;��8y{1�ZXɤ9�����t�2ވ�Fo/�\r�RޣX�^��\"�cjz�`Ͳ0��]��SU�S�f�hm�o�\r�.\r�K��E���h6@�'�����Xإ5\rU`��W;�t����{@��\v��;��Z����R�=}O �%�\t�M��n�͓\v�U�>���`��\n��HC�V\f�\r�\rL��e�]\r.ҺE:-\a�׺e�J�mk=��b��u�\\�O�@�'P�Jk�N���\0!+��`>d�b�\f�GYp�߾]&9>�$[׾0*c������\n������_�ǋ$%\aW~�-ŉ3�׺�?��So�9}��g.���o�R]$�<���:m��cTfJ��T�\\��g!�d���.�\f~=z��i����i%��x�u\ac[z� �=��vڶ����\0w{�MԶS#�Z�����?�ڕ��q'�'�뻏�糘��<���?\0\0\0���=kw۶����\nŻ�M�zY��>M����<�M��w%�H�-J�Iʎ+��\f\0�$ʲ�$ݻ��\"��`0�\f ������t��i<���,ر>9oҧ/`}�b��tm�uh3��+m���}x�n_�{��i��n�m�p6���k�vH���\v�N�N�u���}�������.+��\\j��������_0���g����W�1�#z��P轶aza�ć��>�q��7T���{��J��\v9�i�ݡ=��1����m�v�V�5�]�%���sN�J��t<)�G*��ˡ&��i����'J��\f��w��݇44��p��;���S^���*������rU�|��h�\n�_�J������dm>���|���Z��P0��ҽ�������n��=�Al�:Ǣm��vu�G\\b;m����:�Qgt�S:���c����CM���C8_g�\\�m6ZZ���~&\v|-�y��l������*�xR�����C��Wp��?�1������6P�v�۱�v�8�I�v������?��_�'~��i�ڟ�G0�(�R�O�7;]�q�pM��|GSx�=>iꯢ�\r]�u=[Jz{�\r���W��[>y~�����<���q�=���c�m\v<��i�6�v϶m�=m�M���N��c�n᥼\a�������`j)�'�~��>�E�Z7�z#U�Z������������\a���Aw��N���O\rr�lش�l6�ӆ�j`��h�n�i�J'�N�>����[�89�D�'\r����O\n��G��������y�u�2H[��NlòZ�.�؝.9u;n��7,j��'��O����`j)��-�\a��f���Cn�݃�C��ϡ�lgW���5����$�\"�]�_��@t�ݽg��\"���7�AEc����|O\\�U���9�k�]|�=��=}nę�>��y0��a1�|�o�wG��G��U~�Uq�d6s�\0�˄�-K��v�XR+��t\n�p��/i�Y�TY/�F�c\t���,��x��Զ�8�2>b�\\�|�Rg�\nڧ�6�-�@�Y��������ȧ&��o�\v�*(,��\t|�Ӡ�������e\0f�6����Dd�SU��O�D;z��+j>b�o(�)���k�1R ����������j:ǧE*x�L<TՉ�$��Lj��`�K������?�j^��q�������qd:4�ߠ�X���z\rw���0XL�J`���{������\a��4��W\"s���dW\0!X'�C�O�I%2ȿ�+$��*��3f��l�KK�#D\a�[��c�GQ�>W���2T�%����N�Y���\0�ȧ�'^Z%����g���\0*\fU�6�&.�)^=���4�b���o$|G�).�2Q��ZO�v����M�2�8�as�7�����\fj�g�t�\a�V��AG뜶��ޭ�:�\v� \"����Z:��f4����;�h>E��j\r��ڒB����iF��u�Z�ox��k=M��Z�m�|qѢR����5\f��l�2�S�g��i�a/�o��,�W^�:�F�_+~�G�����֏��������F�jN�����~{J���ͧk�9�a�o�T��{1�G�[(+P��L���z�X6�L\f�}�������~k5V�������7�n/�_�!�|�+���)�&ܻ������7ƞS[���>��.�9������5K�C���yTQ��ݩ�闪�IX���_D4����jfm\r�\f��o}���V�߯A�$6��Q�����9�Nޙb6���V�9H:�����ڱ7��7xz�B�nh:���m���\t�\t� ��0Y,P^�8\\Q���e3H\t7��=pa���J���qգ������F%aHn�k/��OY��Cê������(�^�\r\v��1�N��0\0h��4\fT�;�2�6*�t\\��Z����Iا�de๲�`:�x�9�Y\0���]�L}�$�O�x:��ue���I����\b��cIqL`��s91��T�Ǘ��YtY fl�Ƌ��f#8J6*,p�`~��8�b:�#�Ts�\0ؑ2���UeEo6*��\r�x��#�2j���mTB�쟒����ᒆ�\\�B�\rX�������|&�Ӷ����o��@�������JRTGԏ�a�����\0ȧY��\a��4@����\0�ڄlp��WZ�`�q��[�|3K�\"���!�ED�5�\f8�)=^�L�(%\tvc�1<� �y�0�� \n�bi�U4����P�nO���9�w\r5S���ڝ߶�p��Ӡ0�P�@��T�&-�~���fP��Q\0.(\0\n�0�;�C�&�� �����u\b-����T\t�5\v��*n,޺��|/p�2�XB��:��kPL��m�X\n��W�?�`�)��e¨��ŽY�邀�:/���#��\rǷ�B�R\\h\a\fc71�����M��\"�=�� ����LQ�\a��hm�6�a+�V\t�x�r�T!څ�\"V�����ed�����|'\".\t��zN.AD֒!���I4Ή���m��ԗNZ�<�\aP�81�s�\0�阇\f��챉�Mxlp����\t�2:\"���S�l�d/o\f-I�_��o#��y��\a\bt����ZS3�zxjjm�g�X��?�/�\a߅%������β��ou��_a@8d�A��\t��\t�QW3�$���O���wH��eXO�ϴ����DF�FF��J���ȩ+����H;וO�@�����lL,(���w��\aU�_��;\0cu(��N�jq,�Ĥ83�:P?T*0CiV�6���B!�`(}Z���W\v�dI�9�O�E�j7]�\\dM`u�;\rEη��`X�5Yģ(�(g_��<�����/�k��x�\t9�ϣd$+�\a�FU��t,�@G'J�\0{so5O�M�gI\b�ԏ�����Х����my�,�f�.��Ip�\t�+\0`�])\aI����^���-����(�P{�������-I�v`��APW��c\a��\t.��Lv������d�J��������»�VB� $�0�\bfd�noF�yN�������w�L�M�/��b/� #�eK�+v8X��!��Y��a�7͵�9{��:\b/��ۘ���c�j�4>Є,ڈ�9���Vx#�j��w`��N҆J#4L��\r�#�3�4xƅ�HK��}�X�Y� *���y�� k{��a2í�=C|��-ȵ7A�\r�ӆ��@��\0�+�э��n�S�ٔϿ�n(�����+\b���uG��łڠ�A���T1��B�\r3ƀ\n\r:��|@�M&%s�p�̎A\rRެMb�A]���:�rЅ�y�Q�\a�{�Ovy��n���L�IN����|�'������v�9q\0O\0�+A�%dNnIrӜ3��B7��JG�����[�`G#��t产�R��Py�#�ق�\a���'�9�\a��i쌴�\0T\t�Bfy�(Z�gѦE��^$Y���)�!��x2\\��\a�܉���|��|\v\"M�-O4Ȕ��f�K\n�<�z�G���b�;�@|ASz�T��4��e)��+�rl��\r���TcԲo�XX��n^��ǚ�%�ݒ�\b����\b�dI��\b~�@F-�$�棈�&�8\"ɜ�I��x\\j�B\n�̿�[ޝCuL�OG\a��}�2Ly������GB�����bҗ���3k>�pm��ֱ$�U;TE� ��7�5�����_���\0��\ft���\f|/�>�����Z-�U�P$>�1��h�d�Q$��$�\na�n\b�^.u�s��`x�$�\rj\r���3<�ԙ����!�l�m��OW��X����O���}cf��D\09F.j�ӫ���Y��h�`8��F���r��]tq�,���ZW[+rn0\\�����C�%�0P(ڋ\0��\v�uJy1��:'v��/K��y�[����A��&2��)1�rfG�M/���2�)�f8$L��dD�ü}��i�HIF���\f�8B�������epCå��\b��bV�/��N`]����\rBЯ N^�h筮��;���G2����\t��\fYi�(/\n\"\f��H_h������9�9�|}�3E9�_֗$Z�g+���OY����<��,��ja�@N�����C|�`H�����D�`���0N\v��`�Oc��L���3�<66��Y��J!�S�ms2�k��ؗ4�HT���Ku�.�+\0��)���J�Id��7 #5�\r��c�*��#�����\b���,a�#�6�\bc.1��j*�+�=\f�źW��\bC���P��\f����]��l��93���K+������5�k0L�,FmEX���3�ٴ˗���2Cc\n�a�>�����@r��pb�4���JCc�C�yǱ�ǣ��1��\t�f�Fo�&�M�x���eLJ�1�Q�䍳�ΫHP�������B=�&\a��cM�Ԫ����|s��\n�;h��H)X!%�ͦ4�</ߑ�mk\ng�x�b��^\vwJ#�9��O�^r�\v����;�%��83� �*Q�\t/{�¹��g=�{���UW�:\f�C쮮Q����6cL�B��E4�k6�F�Ϟ�i��p��:x���������_�}�Ub���N`3�qJ�h�{�,\r$���&����3�s��5q\"�e��還eRt�ߣ���oh�%�&�\t�ֺ�\\����߁�n:�����\"�l,�8��v�g�I��L��tR�O7.��`g�L5����[|1I�Q�Zuh�n+ui@?/�占̆Ԓ@��V}<\\�@�@�Q��� ��ՎJ�$R3׭\n���*�ި[��=\r�|�(ߊ��4�n����v�rDqL�)�������U^*����\f��`\\�0g@�R�;RJ��$J����S�8���ff���΃k�����\n���t�^v���3c�.W�Ĳ�X�\0�\tV1�c��X������4J��+��ї�P�1�s�\b�\n�����1��Fլ��\t�t�S`�-lW�(����\f�ht�OI�9���If&J�|����\r�Z�o��U�<�8��pg\vg(JG'^쌍h�@�L\f�ี�Џ�NO���O\b�\fa� ��$l\f���&}�����R��X�.��꬀�����;���E���ڷH��~`��<>�FA�B�$.�W�\tDc%��`y;��E�[��iCYd��HR��:�(�^�)�&<�'rb��\0��\f�j�>(:l�Rƀ�����Ϣ��9�\nYoj\vJ�Z�,Zs�\r�gvN_G)�̂9�/�/C/\b�?�UCo��4)Ur���T\tc\v�Z��H��\t�n����X�7ŤƎz�ϼ�=y/�_�-�bEX9/��z�Vj�D=�.�%����r�?��A�r/���Kvz�L����:\f5�su�e����G/P��̗>��toT�\r�2C�Jo>�{��qx�^S�ԂPUh���VN�-�6h5���'���FR��{��\0�\r܋�*�yA��x�T)�E$h�U<�X�O>A��\r�(q�k$Ni�nu*y['j�-/D*�g��i�A�����P�=�Q�ƞ&�x��#��'2����):��w!җ���h�*��fG=˒W�b��]����d��!���\bìށ�s/��z�E֎�ތ^\\�4x����*W��������YL�%M�X�lO��` e�-�\a��H9�Xp����)C�\0�\f��H\v���9���#��۞��L��6w\vp���y�����$���\vT']����R�'H��Ir��l58���$[������,�$χ�/�����׳�ʅ�(}��F1�yl�o����):f�s�F\t7��e!�t�WE:x��-�U����RiF�:��9�O�#���Y:|s(\"A�aLz+r*(����scYQ�C��\"��\"��$���k�m���Lk��ND�G~n���S��\"<\a�\v�*G'�L'��s�30�\"�lYp^ʽ\f��:��K�+�=��0sLK�7��w�\"2EE/�g�\ve��撹�W&�j\a|���>��KvH��S�c�?AT^��I?���e���M,6��2��&�O�0��*ƌA��R�s.O@Z��,�J�o?��+K����;6\f�0ϋR�SY����scB������'�=*%I�T�u���b��|N���dB�Z/�*l��9Z���7���CV�f����vSJ��T�+��L��*C���w�ךin��&Ksb���������'�.�-��۬��R˯��+L�RL�\vQ ���\\mX�����j3����F��Q꙱�3�q=s}M��5�žA�ԷF���+R�~�ΉFCM{���q���g�\0��~B����@�C}r��h�L��/T/�������8X�S�8��+�~&�,l�ٹ���\\����U����uIun/���-@��/dȒ�]����Z�s��d�5XX \n5���ӻ���R����y�6��Ǔ���4�����@$��Q�!1P����5fo���/\\�b��h6/\\����\r�����Kp�ȼ��\bV\nzTc��yn�\"�b~�\t'��������ɑ�r��}�W��O�Uf��\"< eJ�`A��8��\a�*ʫ�\a�Y�R���r���RB*���y�`�w�2���~��j�R�ݣ�w1 �V1�]�^�5\tP��&N�i�����[rb�ފ�.XE�9��E��<9�l$�&U��c�<Ҝƛ!CW��r�\vܾ�\b)wh\vֵ��Pd�%�&<6��b�\a�]��1K�\n�+=t��3l�Q�A�fp����<٬��0G��dA���˓�H�+��DùE+��f�$����݄�-�PO�y�����vK��8VN��t4x9*���t6[�^���-\v���j���,�Ρ���ҍ�Wp���Qm#�eOYovV}���G%E�����x�&���4��ؘ�Gī�z�߀g�ԍ��4�7~ӕH��t�8�T���`���7bu�~��)�RO��A�.°!KG,���k��F^v����1��D\v��1��4�\t�w��Yw|^-���w���?���-#��V@�^q�l�S)��'���S߉�v\"�{�D�+�V1Z�G�[�٩�v��\a���}\n\b�_��awe�\0\0\0�������E=�#�Xh&hɝ^V1��5f���]��4H9��a�>��\0���4�\0-�Ι�\0\0"
```

I tried using Webclient.Encoding, and adding a User-Agent, but both don't have any influence on the return.

Comment: What is the HTTP status code for the wrong response?

Comment: Looks as though certain responses are compressed. You can see how to decompress the response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2973208/2015959).

Comment: @MarcelN. the responseheader does not include the status code.
ByteBlast you seem to be right. Good response header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, other response header: Content-Encoding: gzip

I'll try the link. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ByteBlast pointed out, the response is sometimes compressed. The linked article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata) adds an automatic gzip decompression.

WebClient.ResponseHeaders has an optional tag of Content-Encoding with which you can manually check if it is encoded/compressed.