# Downloading HTML from thepiratebay

Tags: c#, httprequest

I've searched here and on other sites, the solution for most of them was to set the encoding or send user agent with the request.

It doesn't work out for me though when trying to download from thepiratebay.
I've tried adding a user agent to the header (using whatsmyuseragent), tried setting the encoding (to every type available) and also tried to send a full fake header (started a web project and used the request to see which headers are normally sent) but all to no avail.

EDIT:

I'm getting some weird gibberish but I can't copy it because it doesn't show on the magnify

```
public static string GetPageHTML(string strUrl)
        {
            WebClient wcClient = new WebClient();
            string strHtml = null;

            try
            {
                wcClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "max-age=0";
                //wcClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Connection] = "keep-alive";
                wcClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
                wcClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip,deflate,sdch";
                wcClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6";
                wcClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "thepiratebay.se";
                wcClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.103 Safari/537.36";
                wcClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                strHtml = wcClient.DownloadString(strUrl);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return (strHtml);
        }
```

Comment: Also note that if you're from certain countries you might be blocked from accessing TPB entirely (i.e, the UK)

Comment: @DanPantry No restriction in my country, I can access it freely from the web browser

Comment: You'll need to explain your issue a bit more then. We need to see the code that actually sends the request, not JUST the HTTP Header preparation. That's like showing me a picture of a cake without actually giving me the cake and telling me to eat the cake.

Comment: @DanPantry After all of that code above I call the DownloadString method and it returns a string that contains gibberish characters. When I use the magnifying tool in the locals window, all I see is ‹

Comment: You should still edit your original post with all code concerning the http connection. The gibberish characters sounds like you're trying to connect via HTTPS..

Comment: @DanPantry Posted entire function, the parameter is http://thepiratebay.se/browse/207/0/7

Comment: Get rid of the empty catch blocks and look at the exception you get.

Comment: This is a big reason not to have empty catch blocks because all it does is hide problems and make them harder to debug.

Comment: @emodendroket There is no exception. I get gibberish characters. And they are empty because the code there is irrelevant to the issue, not because it is empty.

Comment: [The problem is that you are not decompressing the GZip/Deflate response, you will need this in order to have normal HTML as result.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata) Either that or use HttpWebRequest directly.

Comment: And you dont need any of those lines you had previously, no user-agent site or anything just the enconding, should be just fine.

Comment: @Prix: Arghh, did not see your comment before posting, but you dont actually need any headers. TPB seems to send gzip response regardless if you ask for it or not ;p