# WebClient.DownloadString() result has encoding issues with some web sites! with persian(farsi) language

Tags: c#, persian

I would like to open a web site and read source of that.
so I wrote this code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.varzesh3.com");
```

but I got a garbage data.
I also add this codes but still it does not work.

```
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8; client.Headers.Add("charset", "utf-8");
```

In addition, I use this codes but none of them did not work:

```
byte[] raw = client.DownloadData("http://www.varzesh3.com");

string webData1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(raw);
string webData2 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(raw);
string webData3 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(raw);
string webData4 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(raw);
string webData5 = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(raw);
string webData6 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
```

note:
I can open and read any other website which uses persian(farsi) language but I could not open www.varzesh3.com
could you please help me ?

Comment: My guess is that that web site is misconfigured so that its headers don't match its content...

Comment: thank you for guiding me, but how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Well you can download the raw bytes instead, and try to work out what encoding you *should* use...

Comment: i use below code but any of encoding does not work :( :
byte[] raw = client.DownloadData("http://www.varzesh3.com");

                string webData1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(raw);
                string webData2 = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(raw);
                string webData3 = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(raw);
                string webData4 = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(raw);
                string webData5 = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(raw);
                string webData6 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);

Comment: Please update our question rather than just adding comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of that site is compressed. You need to decompress it first. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914874/298573). Now by using the [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914874/298573) `MyWebClient`, you will have:

```
using (var client = new MyWebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })
{
    var test = client.DownloadString("http://www.varzesh3.com/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because the website uses [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) to compress the output.
You should decompress it

```
using (var hc = new HttpClient())
using (var stream = await hc.GetStreamAsync(@"http://www.varzesh3.com/"))
using (var gzstream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzstream))
{
    var text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    // do what you want with text
}
```