# webClient.DownloadString being blocked by some websites and responds back as detected malware

Tags: vb.net, downloadstring

I am very new to coding and the code client.DownloadString works on most sites but I have come across a site that seems to block the attempt to load the webpage and returns the same response of blocking the attempt.
I was hoping someone can tell me a way around
here is the code and the page that won't load

```
  ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
  Dim client = New WebClient()
  TextBox1.Text = client.DownloadString("https://www.somesite.com/samsung-series-9-7-1-4-channel.html")
```

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: `DownloadString` performs a simple HTTP GET. It's the remote site itself that decided it doesn't like you, probably because you hammered it with too many requests, or because your IP appears too many times in their logs without any obvious reason (ie purchase). Server owners *really don't like* to pay for servers and power just to serve crawlers, especially when the crawler is used by a competitor. For them, your code *is* malware.

Comment: What response do you get? What status code? A 429 response means that you sent too many requests and just need to slow down. It doesn't mean you got block. You just have to throttle your requests. A different status code though, like a 400 or 404 or even a timeout may mean you got blocked. In that case you won't be able to make requests again until they remove the block

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, not a competitor, trying to automate a tool for one of their sub-divisions and the code stopped working recently. I can access their pages from Chrome so IP is not being blocked. It detects a ROBOT crawl behaviour (which is the case) and blocks it .. the response is  <html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script>
<body>
</body></html>

Comment: That's not a rejection, that's a response specifically created for crawlers. I suspect the server saw there's no `User-Agent` header in the request, realized the request came from a bot and sent back the canned response. Add a `user-agent` header [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841540/setting-the-user-agent-header-for-a-webclient-request).

Comment: Different servers send different `user-agent` strings. You can google for a list or you can use `Fiddler` or your browser's Developer Tools to inspect requests in the `Network` tab and see what it sends

Comment: They *really* hate bots. I tried sending a User Agent header a couple of times and now my *browser* displays a verification page! Just ask them what you should do to avoid rejections. They may be able to just whitelist your IP and be done with it

Comment: Thank you so much Panagiotis, that worked! Legend!