# C# WebClient - DownloadString bad encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webrequest, webclient

I'm trying to download an html document from Amazon but for some reason I get a bad encoded string like "��K��g��g�e".

Here's the code I tried:

```
using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    var url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07H256MBK/";
    webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Same thing happens when using HttpClient:

```
var url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07H256MBK/";
var httpclient = new HttpClient();
var html = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(url);
```

I also tried reading the result in Bytes and then convert it back to UTF-8 but I still get the same result. Also note that this DOES NOT always happen. For example, yesterday I was running this code for ~2 hours and I was getting a correctly encoded HTML document. However today I always get a bad encoded result. It happens every other day so it's not a one time thing.

==================================================================

However when I use the HtmlAgilitypack's wrapper it works as expected **everytime**:

```
var url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07H256MBK/";
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = htmlWeb.Load(url);
```

What causes the WebClient and HttpClient to get a bad encoded string even when I explicitly define the correct encoding? And how does the HtmlAgilityPack's wrapper works by default?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check the "Content-Type" header, it contains the used encoding. Do not take UTF8 for granted. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fired up Firefox's web dev tools, requested that page, and looked at the response headers:

[image: Response headers]

See that `content-encoding: gzip`? That means the response is gzip-encoded.

It turns out that Amazon gives you a response compressed with gzip even when you *don't* send an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header (verified with another tool). This is a bit naughty, but not that uncommon, and easy to work around.

This wasn't a problem with character encodings at all. `HttpClient` is good at figuring out the correct encoding from the `Content-Type` header.

You can tell `HttpClient` to un-zip responses with:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip,
};

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    // your code
}
```

This will be set automatically if you're using the NuGet package versions 4.1.0 to 4.3.2, otherwise you'll need to do it yourself.

You can do the same with WebClient, [but it's harder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914874/1086121).

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!