# I get wrong file when I download it by C# code

Tags: c#, excel, download, webclient

When I open this excel file [link](http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0) in my browser, It will be downloaded successfully.
But when I download it by the following c# code

```
private void downloadFile()
    {
        string remoteUri = "http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0";
        string fileName = @"g:\temp.xlsx";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
        }
    }
```

and I open it in the file explorer, I get the file format error:

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: are you sure the workbook at that link is a .xlsx file type?

Comment: @ArcherBird Click the link and download it and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unzip file and write.

```
        string remoteUri = "http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0";
        string fileName = @"g:\temp.xlsx";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            using var stream = client.OpenRead(remoteUri);
            using var zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
            using var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
            zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, resultStream.ToArray());

        }
```

Comment: How do you know that the file is compressed and needs manual decompression? Why doesn't WebClient do the decompression automatically? The compression part should be a silent part of the download, the client shouldn't say that it accepts compressed contents if it doesn't and the server shouldn't respond with compressed content if the client doesn't say that it accepts it. So again, how do you know the file is compressed?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is a problem specific solution. Default behavior of `WebClient` is non autodecompress.  If we have general purpose downloader, we can inherit `WebClient` and override `GetWebRequest` method like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata

Comment: But does the WebClient say that it *accepts* compressed content?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It is possible to do the decompression silently. It all depends on how your client is setup. For example in my answer, i have setup the httpclient to decompress content automatically via handler. With that in place, the httpclient can automatically decompress the data and provide it to you. No need to worry about whether the response was compressed or not by the server.

Comment: My point is that serving compressed content is a contract between the client and the server. If the client says that it can accept compressed encoding, and the server supports it, it can serve compressed content, saying that it is compressed. If the WebClient class doesn't decompress silently, why does it say that it accepts compressed content? And if it doesn't, why the server serve compressed content? Either way, there are two answers here just saying "The server is serving compressed content" and my question is still how you definitely know that.

Comment: Not as in "If you inspect the headers you can learn that the server served compressed content", I'm asking how **you**, the two of you that answered this, knows that **this** server serves compressed content? In this particular case?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did not knew it until i inspected the response headers. I took the sample code and ran it inside of a console application to figure out the actual response that was provided by the server. Otherwise the only other option would have been to go through the documentation of api which the OP has not provided.

Comment: Then shouldn't that part of the mystery be part of the answer? In the future, if someone comes here wondering why WebClient is producing corrupt files, how will they know whether compression or not is the answer in their case?

Comment: I still contend that the server in this case is in error. WebClient is not going to state that it accepts compressed content if it does not deal with decompression, so if the server is serving compressed content it is in breach of contract. It should serve it uncompressed. But that is completely besides the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the response headers provided by the remoteUri, you will notice that the particular endpoint is actually serving content in compressed format.

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

[image: Response Headers Snap]

So the content you get back is not a direct excel file, rather a zip file. So for the piece of code to work, the file name should be *`temp.zip`* instead of *`temp.xlsx`*

```
private void downloadFile()
{
    string remoteUri = "http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0";
    string fileName = @"g:\temp.zip";

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName);
    }
}
```

Having said that, inline is a better approach to download the file.
Create an instance of `HttpClient` by passing in a `HttpClientHandler` which has the `AutomaticDecompression` property set to `DecompressionMethods.GZip` to handle Gzip decompression automatically. Next read the data and save it to `temp.xlsx` file.

```
string remoteUri = "http://members.tsetmc.com/tsev2/excel/MarketWatchPlus.aspx?d=0";
string fileName = @"g:\temp.xlsx";
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var response = await client.GetAsync(remoteUri);

var fileContent = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, fileContent);
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. But the main question is when you click on the link the browser downloads and saves an excel file. what is the difference between my code and browser behavior?

Comment: Browser does a lot more that just downloading the content. It looks at the responses headers and automatically does the decompression for you.

Comment: @VDWWD there is a subtle difference, temp.zip instead of temp.xlsx. which makes all the difference.

Comment: I did not see that. Sorry.

Comment: How do you know it is compressed?

Comment: We can look at the headers of the response for that information. To be more specific, the 'ContentEncoding' header in response had a value of gzip for the request asked in question.