# The remote server returned an error: (413) Payload Too Large. .net WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, http-status-code-413

I'm trying to download a webpage. It was working previously but now I'm getting 413's specifically mentioning 'Payload too large' (unlike what seems to be the normal error message 'Request Entity Too Large')

Here's the code; I've tried all sorts of web config changes suggested in related questions but no luck.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
var page = client.DownloadString(websiteUrl);
```

Comment: add accept encoding with gzip and decompres

Comment: @Selvin Perfect! Your suggestion led me to this answer which worked, tyvm- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata