# Download .webp image from url with C#

Tags: c#, download, webclient, webp

I am trying to download an image from

http://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib/14/7503003936114/7503003936114-01-01-01.jpg

using WebClient.

When I browse the image in Chrome the image is there:
[image]

The url ends in .jpg but the image is in .WEBP format.

```
    using (WebClient wb = new WebClient())
    {                  
         wb.DownloadFile("http://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//14/7503003936114/7503003936114-01-01-01.jpg", "image.jpg");
    }
```

I have tried **.DownloadData(), asyng methods, HttpClient, WebRequest directly.**.. and I am always getting the same error.

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine but this is a server-specific behavior. Adding some request headers fixes the issue.

Here's an example using `HttpClient`

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All // automatically adds HTTP header "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
    });

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading...");
            byte[] data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//14/7503003936114/7503003936114-01-01-01.jpg");
            Console.WriteLine("Saving...");
            File.WriteAllBytes("image.jpg", data);
            Console.WriteLine("OK.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Console output

```
Downloading...
Saving...
OK.
```

Downloaded image

[image]

Comment: My I know where or how did you figure out it was this string?     
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
???

Comment: @Fraga copied from Network log (dev tools) in my Firefox Browser. Probably this string can be shortened or changed ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept)).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is to do with headers. But, let's start you on the right track and teach you one of the more modern ways of making Http Requests using *DI*, *Services*, and `IHttpClientFactory`.

**Service**

```
public class MyFunkyService
{
   private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

   public MyFunkyService(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    => _clientFactory = clientFactory;

   public async Task<byte[]> GetSomeFunkyThingAsync()
   {
      using var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
      using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//14/7503003936114/7503003936114-01-01-01.jpg");

      request.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
      request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.ParseAdd("gzip, deflate");

      using var response = await client
         .SendAsync(request)
         .ConfigureAwait(false);

      response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

      return await response
         .Content
         .ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
         .ConfigureAwait(false);

   }
}
```

**Set up**

```
var provider = new ServiceCollection()
   .AddHttpClient()
   .AddSingleton<MyFunkyService>()
   .BuildServiceProvider();
```

**Usage**

```
// this would be injected 
var myClient = provider.GetRequiredService<MyFunkyService>();

var result = await myClient.GetSomeFunkyThingAsync();
```

<sub>***Note** : there are many many more variations on how you could do this. However at least you are not learning the old and busted ways of doing things*</sub>

Comment: This works too!.. but the solution above by aepot is easier! My problem was the header, its amazing to learn something new! thanks.

Comment: Just interesting, where do you setup `HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression`? Does factory create the client with enabled one by default?

Comment: @aepot good point, i forgot to add ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler to the builder :o

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the server is only serving requests that support compression. `WebClient` doesn't support compression automatically. You can enable support for compression by inheriting your own class as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata).

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression =  DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Then use `MyWebClient` instead of `WebClient`.

Comment: No, I did tried that! and it fails anyway!.. not the first time! but the subsequent calls

https://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//99/7503019554999/7503019554999-01-01-01.jpg
https://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//99/7503001566399/7503001566399-01-01-01.jpg
https://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//99/7502246460899/7502246460899-01-01-01.jpg
https://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//99/0787359175299/0787359175299-01-01-01.jpg
https://aplweb.soriana.com/foto/fotolib//99/0077661134399/0077661134399-01-01-01.jpg