# Timeout with HTTPClient C# on VPS Linux, ping and curl OK, no firewall

Tags: c#, .net, linux

I want to retrieve the content of a page with httpclient. I did a simple method, which works well on visual studio.

```
private async Task<string> Connection(string Url)
{
    using HttpClient client = new();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36 OPR/77.0.4054.277");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");

    double timestamp = GlobalMethod.Timestamp();
    string json = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
    return json;
}
```

But when I run my application on a linux VPS (Ubuntu, host OVH, .NET 5), Httpclient returns an error timeout.

On my VPS, the ping to the url I want to retrieve, and CURL function, works fine. But not the Httpclient.
Same settings of my Postman request, and no problem with it.

Do you have an idea of ​​the problem ?
It looks a lot like this topic, without me understanding how to solve it: [httpClient call in C# goes to timeout, while cUrl is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226068/httpclient-call-in-c-sharp-goes-to-timeout-while-curl-is-working)

API link : [https://api.store.nvidia.com/partner/v1/feinventory?skus=FR~NVGFT070~NVGFT080~NVGFT090~NVLKR30S~NSHRMT01~NVGFT060T~187&locale=FR](https://api.store.nvidia.com/partner/v1/feinventory?skus=FR%7ENVGFT070%7ENVGFT080%7ENVGFT090%7ENVLKR30S%7ENSHRMT01%7ENVGFT060T%7E187&locale=FR)

Thanks !

Error with timeout:

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
> ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
> ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled.
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (125): Operation canceled
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync(Boolean async)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean async, Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Castiel_Bot_Discord.Modules.NvidiaCommand.Connection(String Url) in C:\Users\gaeta\source\repos\Castiel_Bot_Discord\Castiel_Bot_Discord\Modules\NvidiaCommand.cs:line 114
> at Castiel_Bot_Discord.Modules.NvidiaCommand.SearchGpu(String args) in C:\Users\gaeta\source\repos\Castiel_Bot_Discord\Castiel_Bot_Discord\Modules\NvidiaCommand.cs:line 42

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on my Debian machine. Suddenly timeout exception occured for https requests, but I did not performed any configuration steps before at all. The app just stopped to work!
What I've found out to solve:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/47267
According to that you need to disable ipv6. For my host I've changed sysctl.conf as described here: https://wiki.it-kb.ru/unix-linux/debian/how-to-turn-off-ipv6-in-debian-linux
Now the timeout issue solved for me.

Comment: Thanks, but disabling ipv6 does not solve the problem for me

Comment: @Castiel were you able to figure out the issue?