# Downloading JSON with WebClient results in weird unicode-like characters?

Tags: c#

So I can make a request in my browser to,
https://search.snapchat.com/lookupStory?id=itsmaxwyatt

and it will give me back JSON, but if I do it via web client, it seems to give me back a very obfuscated string? I can provide it all, but have truncated for now:

�x��ƽ���������o�Cj�_�����˗��89:�/�[��/� h��#l���ٗC��U.�gH�,����qOv�_� �_����σҭ

So, here is the Csharp code:

```
using var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add ("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0");
webClient.Headers.Add("Host", "search.snapchat.com");
webClient.DownloadString("https://search.snapchat.com/lookupStory?id=itsmaxwyatt")
```

I have also tried in a http rest client without any headers, and it still returns JSON.

Tried with encoding:

```
using var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
webClient.Headers.Add ("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0");
webClient.Headers.Add("Host", "search.snapchat.com");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData("https://search.snapchat.com/lookupStory?id=itsmaxwyatt")));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically decompress gzip response via WebClient.DownloadData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973208/automatically-decompress-gzip-response-via-webclient-downloaddata)

Comment: so I have updated my question with a code example using this approach, but still very cryptic response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Progman comment, all you need is to do the following:

```
// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
void Main()
{
    using var webClient = new MyWebClient();
    webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0");
    webClient.Headers.Add("Host", "search.snapchat.com");
    var str = webClient.DownloadString("https://search.snapchat.com/lookupStory?id=itsmaxwyatt");
    Debug.WriteLine(str);
}
```