# Grabbing content from a website in C#

Tags: c#

New to C# here, but I've used Java for years. I tried googling this and got a couple of answers that were not quite what I need. I'd like to grab the (X)HTML from a website and then use DOM (actually, CSS selectors are preferable, but whatever works) to grab a particular element. How exactly is this done in C#?

Comment: Could you add some example code for us to work with?

Comment: It's too bad comments can't be downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

To get the HTML you can use the **WebClient** object.

To parse the HTML you can use **HTMLAgility** librrary.

Answer (score 2):

```
// prepare the web page we will be asking for
        HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

        // execute the request
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        // we will read data via the response stream
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int    count      = 0;
        do
        {
            // fill the buffer with data
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            // make sure we read some data
                if (count != 0)
            {
            // translate from bytes to ASCII text
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

            // continue building the string
            sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0); // any more data to read?
```

Then use Xquery expressions or Regex to grab the element you need

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.Net.WebClient` or `System.Net.HttpWebrequest` to fetch the page but parsing for the elements is not supported by the classes.

Use **HtmlAgilityPack** (http://html-agility-pack.net/)

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
htmlWeb.UseCookies = true;


HtmlDocument htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load(url);


// after getting the document node
// you can do something like this
foreach (HtmlNode item in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("input"))
{ 
    // item mathces your req
    // take the item.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hear you want to use the [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for working with HTML files. This will give you Linq access, with is *A Good Thing (tm)*. You can download the file with [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to load html and find the element you need.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, you can fairly easily use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx#Y6555) to get the contents of a URL. From there, you will have to do something to parse out the HTML. That is where it starts to get tricky. You can't use a normal XML parser, because many (most?) web site HTML pages aren't 100% valid XML. Web browsers have specially implemented parsers to work around the invalid portions. In Ruby, I would use something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse the HTML, so you might want to look for a .NET port of it, or another parser specificly designed to read HTML.

---

Edit:

Since the topic is likely to come up: [WebClient vs. HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694388/webclient-vs-httpwebrequest-httpwebresponse)

Also, thanks to the others that answered for noting HtmlAgility. I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the html agility pack, which is one of the more common libraries for parsing html.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/