# c#:sending message using fullonsms api

Tags: c#

i was trying to send message from a C# website to phone number.i used full on sms api. tried this many time but the message is not sending only.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string uid;
    string password;
    string message;
    string no;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
   //This is the code of API for sending message.
    public void send()
    {
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://ubaid.tk/sms/sms.aspx?uid=" + uid + "&pwd=" + password + "&msg=" + message + "&phone=" + no + "&provider=fullonsms");
        HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
        string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        respStreamReader.Close();
        myResp.Close();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            uid = "";
            password = "";
            message = TextBox2.Text;
            no = TextBox1.Text;
            send();
            TextBox2.Text = "";
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
```

i have registered for fullosms with my number.But not getting the solution for this.somebody please help

Comment: Have you confirmed that the WebRequest is working or not in that URL?

Comment: This question is dupicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173975/how-to-send-sms-to-different-phone-number). Check there if it solves your query.

Comment: sir please tell me why it is not working? i am very new to asp.net