# Send byte array from one site to another (and back)

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, post

I control both sites so any method will do.

There must be a simpler way then the following:

```
byte[] result;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://blahblah.com/blah.ashx");
byte[] inputToSend = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
request.Timeout = 30 * 1000;
request.ContentLength = inputToSend.Length;
using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    stream.Write(inputToSend, 0, inputToSend.Length);
request.Headers.Add("blah", "more blah");//This is for authentication.
WebResponse r = request.GetResponse();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    r.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
    result = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Not so?

(The code is the requesting side. The responder is simpler.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a WebClient response after posting data? (.NET)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014935/how-to-read-a-webclient-response-after-posting-data-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially use the `WebClient` to make the code smaller. Specifically, the [UploadData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    wc.UploadData(yourUrl, inputToSend);
}
```

..and to download:

```
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    var receivedData = wc.DownloadData(yourUri);
}
```

You can add whatever headers you need via the WebClient `Headers` property:

```
wc.Headers.Add("blah", "blah"); // your auth stuff here.
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. But is there a way to request+response with WebClient? (The received data is in response to the sent data)

Comment: OK. Never mind - I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1014944/939213 showing that `UploadData` returns a response.